# How to style text in .html() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to style text inside the html() like `color:red; font-weight:bold`. How can I do that within the jQuery itself? I can style the div with `id=login_result` in html, but every text here will be red and bold. I just want these error texts like below to be red only. Many thanks

```
var login_result = $('#login_result');

if ($.trim(email.val()).length == 0) {
    email.focus(); // focus to the filed
    login_result.html('<span> Email field is required</span>');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a class to the span and define it in your stylesheet:

```js
var login_result = $('#login_result');
if ($.trim(email.val()).length == 0) {
  email.focus(); // focus to the filed
  login_result.html('<span class="error"> Email field is required</span>');
  return false;
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

Compared to the solution of Brad Martin this has the advantage, that all information regarding styles is set in your stylesheet and not in the javascript which should mostly handle application logic.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this method before asking this question but i did not clear cache and it did not work as expected. I thought I did something wrong. Now i saw your answer and yes problem came from caching.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the .css() method at the end of your login_result.html('') line

```
var login_result = $('#login_result');
if ($.trim(email.val()).length == 0) {
    email.focus(); // focus to the filed
    login_result.html('<span> Email field is required</span>').css('color', 'red');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will add the styling to `#login_result` instead of the span.

Comment: Gotcha, was just an off the cuff answer to get the user to try some methods and learn a bit. Seems like he already had some decent jQuery knowledge and if you look at the docs it wouldn't be too hard to find his own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
login_result
   .html('<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Email field is required</span>');
```

Or:

```
login_result.html('<span>Email field is required</span>');
login_result.find('span').css({'color': 'red', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
```

But the preferable practice would be to make use of CSS classes:

```
login_result.html('<span class="validation-message">Email field is required</span>');
```

(then put the necessary styles in a CSS file).

Answer (score 0):

After inserting the new html, the css will apply so for example:

```
#login_result span {
    color:red
}
```

will made your new span text red.

Answer (score 0):

First add class to the span element

```
if ($.trim(email.val()).length == 0) {
    email.focus(); // focus to the filed
    login_result.html($('<span> Email field is required</span>').addClass('error'));
    return false;
}
```

Then describe that class in CSS file

```
.error{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```